# connected and quasi-connected separators of a space

Tags: gn.general-topology

Does there exist a connected topological space $X$ and a subset $A\subseteq X$ such that no connected component of $A$ separates $X$, but some quasi-component of $A$ separates $X$?

Meaning $X\setminus C$ is connected for every connected component $C$ of $A$, but there is a quasi-component (intersection of all relatively clopen sets of $A$ containing a particular point) $Q$ of $A$ such that $X\setminus Q$ is disconnected?

Here is my idea.

Let $S$ be the dyadic solenoid.  Let $X_0$ and $X_1$ be two disjoint [composants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composant) of $S$.  Let $\alpha\simeq [0,1]$ be an arc in $X_0$.  Let $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$ be disjoint countable dense subsets of $\alpha$, like disjoint rationals. Define $X=(X_0\setminus \delta_0)\cup (X_1\cup \delta_1)$.  The topology on $X$ will be generated by the Solenoid subspace  topology together with the sets $X_0\setminus \delta_0$ and $X_1\cup \delta_1$.

1. $X$ is connected.
2. Let $A$ be a be a closed Solenoid neighborhood of $\alpha$ such
   that $A\neq X$.  Then $\alpha\setminus \delta_0$ is contained in a
   quasi-component $Q$ of $A$.  To see this, note that an irrational set
   in $\alpha\setminus (\delta_0\cup \delta_1)$ is retained by $X$, and
   the basic neighborhoods at these points are precisely the Solenoid
   neighborhoods.  A sequence of arcs in $X$ uniformly limits to this
   set, so $$\alpha\setminus (\delta_0\cup \delta_1)\subseteq Q.$$ Since
   $Q$ is closed, $\alpha\setminus \delta_0\subseteq Q$.
3. Each connected component of $\alpha\setminus \delta_0$ is a
   singleton which does not separate $X$.
4. $X\setminus \delta_1$ is the union of two separated sets
   $X_0\setminus \delta_1$ and $X_1\setminus \delta_1$.

Does this sound right?  The topology will only be Hausdorff, and of course ultimately I'd like regular or metrizable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.  Let $X$ be $({\mathbb{R}}^2 \setminus (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})) \cup \{(0,0),(0,1)\}) $, that is, $X$ is the plane with all points on the $y$-axis removed except for the points $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  Let $A = (\{ \frac{1}{n} : n = 1, 2, \cdots \} \times [0,1]) \cup \{(0,0), (0,1)\}$. Then the components of $A$ are the line segments $\{\frac{1}{n}\} \times [0,1]$ along with the singletons $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\{(0,1)\}$.  None of these components disconnect $X$ but the quasi-component $\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ does disconnect $X$.